# Is there a way to execute a file knowing only the subdirectory?

Tags: python, exec

I have two exe files located at
C:\Users\Bella\Desktop\Folder\fuctions
I want to write a python script that would open them both from Desktop\Folder, The issue is I want to share this script with people and I won't know the name of their User,
Is there a way to execute the files while only knowing it will be in Folder\functions since I will always know that my script will be located in "Folder"

```
import os
os.startfile(r"C:\Users\Bella\Desktop\Folder\Dist\fuctions\Test.exe")
os.startfile(r"C:\Users\Bella\Desktop\Folder\Dist\fuctions\Test2.exe")
```

obviously that wont work when shared to friends

Comment: Use a relative path instead of an absolute one - simply start your path with "Dist\fuctions...".

Answer (score 0):

You can use relative path as mentioned in the comments or use:

```
import os

# get the directory of the file
dir = os.path.realpath('...')

# append the remainder of the path
path = os.path.join(dir, 'Dist\fuctions\Test.exe')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use os.environ.get("USERNAME")
It gets the username of the user.

```
import os
username = os.environ.get("USERNAME")
os.startfile(f"C:\\Users\\{username}\\Desktop\\Folder\\Dist\\fuctions\\Test.exe")
os.startfile(r=f"C:\\Users\\{username}\\Desktop\\Folder\\Dist\\fuctions\\Test2.exe")
```

Or you can use os.getlogin()

```
import os
username = os.getlogin()
os.startfile(f"C:\\Users\\{username}\\Desktop\\Folder\\Dist\\fuctions\\Test.exe")
os.startfile(r=f"C:\\Users\\{username}\\Desktop\\Folder\\Dist\\fuctions\\Test2.exe")
```

Upvote if it works :)

Comment: Also it is not good practice to use absolute paths
Use relatives path using os.getcwd() and os.path.join(cwd , "path//to//the//exe) (Works only if the exe is in a sub directory in the place where the python code is loacted)